# client side jQuery variable within node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js

I have html markup in node.js, using jQuery for an ajax call there is callback object `data`. 
When i output `data` in console every thing works well, but when i try to output into the DOM i cant seem to reference it as a variable.
How can i make this work? Am i going about this correctly?

```
exports.serve = function(req, res) {
var content = '<html>\
<head></head>\
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>\
<script type="text/javascript">\
$(function(){\
    $(".ajaxLI a").click(function(){\
        var mypost = "abc123";\
        $.post( "/ajaxcall?myget=zzz", {mypost:mypost}, function(data){\
            //console.log(data);\n\ // << this works
            $("body").append("<h1>data</h1>");\n\ // << this does not
            //$("body").append("<h1>'+data+'</h1>");\n\ //<< error
        });\
        return false;\
    });\
});\
</script>\
<body>\
<h1>INDEX</h1>\
<ul>\
    <li><a href="./index">index</a></li>\
    <li class="ajaxLI"><a href="./ajaxcall">ajax</a></li>\
    <li><a href="./login?var=123abc">login</a><< variables</li> \
    <li><a href="./admin/login">admin_login</a></li>\
    <li><a href="./admin/index">admin_index</a></li>\
</ul>\
</body>\
</html>';
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
res.end(content);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'data'` is literally the string `data`. You have to concatenate the strings (with consistent quotes):

```
$("body").append("<h1>" + data + "</h1>");
```

Or:

```
$('<h1>', {html: data}).appendTo('body');
```

Comment: this gives an error ` $("body").append("<h1>'+data+'</h1>");\n\`
                                                        ^
ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: @tq: You have to use consistent quotes. Either both `'` or both `"`.

Comment: the quotes are consistent,  if you look above the entire markup is within single quotes

Comment: i see what you mean,  i was breaking out of the single quote and it was looking for a variable outside of the markup